# Adding Table column and column descriptions for a VDS in Dremio Wiki

Tags: wiki, dremio

I'm trying to add a table (VDS) column and description in Dremio WIKI page. In Edit mode of wiki, no issues, it shows Column and Descriptions as (tow column) array.  In display mode, it looses the array form and shows appended column and descriptions with a single blank space in-between.

Any help appreciated on how to add a table (VDS) description (column and Descriptions) in Dremio Wiki?

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. There is no code for this. It is a text in the form of a table like in Word to be included in Dremio Wiki.

Comment: Then your question likely isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and questions directly relating to popular programming applications. I suggest asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

Anand Reddy Demagu who is a contributor to Stack Overflow, gave me the solution. Dremio WIKI supports mark down script.

Below is the wiki mark down script in WIKI Editor
[Sample script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j6Gz.png)

Below is the table Dremio shows in WIKI
[Dremio Wiki Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYsUc.png)